# Why is $561$ missing from this list?

Tags: pseudoprimes

On the MathWorld page:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPseudoprime.html

in the first table, I expect to see $561$ on every line, but it is not on the line for base $3$.

When you click on the link to the OEIS page, it also is missing from the list.  Since $561$ is a Carmichael number, I expected it to be there. Is this a typo (and if so, how do I report it)? If not, what am I missing? Certainly  $3^{561} \equiv 3 \pmod{561}$; is there a different definition of "Fermat pseudoprime" that leaves $561$ out?

Comment: $561$ is divisible by $3$, that's why it's not on that list.

Comment: @GuyFsone  Because it's the exact same question and there were 4 different answers to that question.   Your abusive stalking has been reported.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ divides into $561$, so it is not true that $3^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod {561}$.  The definition on the page calls for this, not for $3^{561} \equiv 3 \pmod {561}$

Answer (score 1):

The definition is that a base $a$ pseudoprime $n$ satisfies $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod a$. But $3^{560} \equiv 375 \mod 561$.

Answer (score 1):

That post says that $q$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $b$ if any only if:

$$b^{q-1}\equiv  1\pmod q$$

It is possible for $b^{q}\equiv b\pmod{q}$ without $b^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$, if $b,q$ are not relatively prime.

Answer (score 1):

Carmichael numbers are composite numbers that are not pseudoprime for all factors of that number. So $561=3\times 11 \times17$  is not a pseudoprime base 3, 11 and 17. Carmichael numbers only needs to be a psuedoprime for a base that is coprime to the Carmichael number.